# display the value of a foreign key with primefaces

Tags: primefaces, datatable, foreign-keys

I have the following datatable which contains a list of pictures. I want to display for ech picture the user who uploaded it.so the user is a foreign key in table picture which is car.utilisateur_nom_ut in the datatable.

XHTML :

```
  <p:dataGrid var="car" value="#{listeGrpBean.pictureList}" columns="2"  id="unique"
    rows="12" paginator="true"
    emptyMessage="Pas de photos partagées dans ce groupe" 
    > 

     <p:panel  header="#{car.description}" style="width:100%">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2"> 

      <h:outputText styleClass="infos_img_title" value="ajoutée le :"/>
        <h:outputText styleClass="infos_img" value="#{car.date_pub}">    
       <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"/>
      </h:outputText>


        <h:outputLabel styleClass="infos_img_title" for="added" value="Ajouté par: "/>
        <h:outputText styleClass="preformatted" value="#{car.utilisateur_nom_ut}" />
      </p:panel>  

     </p:dataGrid>
```

I have the following error :

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /example.xhtml @83,94 value="#{car.utilisateur_nom_ut}": Property 'utilisateur_nom_ut' not found on type com.pfe.domaine.Document
```

Comment: Please post your managed bean and car classes

Comment: here is my Picture class :                                            `@Entity

public class Picture implements Serializable {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
 private int ID_info; 
 private String description; 
 @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
 private Date date_pub;
 @ManyToOne
 private Utilisateur utilisateur; }`

Comment: my manages bean :  
`@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ListeGrpBean implements Serializable {

private List<Picture> pictureList = new ArrayList<Picture>();
private  Groupe selectedUser;
private  Picture selecteddoc;
private boolean panelRendered;                                private InfoDAO docdao = new InfoDaoImpl();
public List<Picture> getPictureList() {
 if (pictureList.size()==0){
  
  pictureList = docdao.docs_groupe();
 }
 return pictureList;
}

public void setPictureList(List<Picture> pictureList) {
 this.pictureList = pictureList;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an output text component in your xhtml ( `<h:outputText styleClass="preformatted" value="#{car.utilisateur_nom_ut}" />`) which is looking for the property utilisateur_nom_ut in your Document class, but you do not have it in this class.

You do have a Utilisateur property though. Is the nom_ut a property of the Utilisateur class instead? If so it should be `#{car.utilisateur.nom_ut}` or whatever is within your utilisateur class

Comment: yes, nom_ut is a property of the Utilisateur class. ok i will try it with #{car.utilisateur.nom_ut}